# Происхождение фамилиии Шиповалов

Tags: этимология, фамилии

Откуда взялась фамилия Шиповалов?
Происхождение похожей фамилиии Шаповалов довольно очевидно — от профессии "шаповал", то есть валяльщик шапок (из шерсти).
Но кто такой "шиповал"?

**Upd.**
На сайте https://1914.svrt.ru, посвященном первой мировой войне, есть [171](https://1914.svrt.ru/extsearch.php?pg=9&surname=%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2&religion%5B0%5D=18&name_ext=1&surname_ext=1#report) Шаповаловых, 3 Шиповаловых и [25](https://1914.svrt.ru/extsearch.php?pg=2&surname=%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2&religion%5B0%5D=18&name_ext=1&surname_ext=1#report) Шеповаловых.
На сайте Одноклассники есть [81 тысяча](https://ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=searchResult&st.mode=Users&st.query=%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2&st.grmode=Groups) Шаповаловых,
[3 тысячи](https://ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=searchResult&st.mode=Users&st.query=%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2&st.grmode=Groups) Шиповаловых и [3,1 тысячи](https://ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=searchResult&st.mode=Users&st.query=%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2&st.grmode=Groups) Шеповаловых.
Получается, в наше время Шиповаловых и Шеповаловых в несколько десятков раз меньше, чем Шаповаловых. Сто лет назад их тоже было меньше, но в другой пропорции.

Шеповаловых я раньше не встречала.

Comment: Может, просто ошибка закралась, как часто бывает?

Comment: @Артём Луговой, это не может быть одноразовая ошибка, потому что фамилия достаточно распространенная. Но, может быть, есть какая-то фонетическая закономерность, что безударное "ша"  имеет большой шанс превратиться в "ши"? Вам известно о таком?

Comment: Нет, не слышал о таком, как и такой фамилии! Шаповаловы часто попадалось, а через И ни разу.

Comment: @Артём Луговой, добавила статистику в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Материал о Шаповаловых Шиповаловых, Шеповаловых  **можно найти в Интернете**, например:

[https://www.nashi-predki.ru/wiki/Шаповалов,_Шеповалов,_Шиповалов](https://www.nashi-predki.ru/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

https://names.neolove.ru/last_names/24/sha/shapovalov.html

2. Можно предположить, что все варианты связаны с написанием фамилии "Шаповалов" **по слуху.** Звук А в безударной позиции после шипящих обычно произносится как И, но точно так же произносится звук, обозначаемый буквай Е. Соответственно, при записи фиксировались все три варианта.